# Asp.net core InProcess Hosting model on Linux or Mac or FreeBsd

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-core, webserver, kestrel

Hi i want to know can we use **InProcess** hosting model on *Linux or Mac or FreeBsd*
Because InProcess model uses **implentation of kestrel**  with **IIS** web server And we can use IIS web server just on Windows Os

So will InProcess model kill cross platform ability of asp.net core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET Core and Kestrel run just fine cross-platform.

The InProcess model is built for Windows with IIS to mitigate performance losses due to forwarding requests to another process and help diagnosing startup (/configuration) errors when running behind IIS.

Since there is no IIS for non-Windows OSes, you can just run the application as a stand-alone application. There is no need for IIS special handling without IIS.

You can also run ASP.NET Core apps as standalone apps / services on Windows without the need for IIS, but a lot of Windows-based infrastructure uses IIS (e.g. Windows-based Azure WebApps or on-premise systems).